# Skipping Calabash Outline Gherkin statements AWS Device Farm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, calabash, calabash-android, aws-device-farm

Currently I am working on Android App automation testing using calabash. I've implemented 200 test cases in Cucumber. In my project has 80% Gherkin statements are non outline statement's and 20% are outline statement's. I am able to run all 200 test cases in real devices as well as simulator also. But when I deployed to AWS Device farm all these test cases, Its skipping Outline statements. May I know how to solve this issue. I don't have time to convert all Outline statements to Non outline statement's. Can you please help me for resolve this issue and I want to know how to debug (Why AWS Device farm is skipping my statements).

Answer (score 0):

I work for the Device Farm team.
Unfortunately, we do not support outline statements. We are actively looking at this item and checking AWS announcements and AWS forums would be the best place to get an update for this.